# url rewriting for address containing dot desh and underscore

Tags: url-rewriting

**Links**

```
<a href='/'>Home</a>
<a href='/contact'>Contact</a>
<a href='/johnsmith'>Profile 1</a>
<a href='/john.smith'>Profile 2</a>
<a href='/john_smith'>Profile 3</a>
<a href='/john-smith'>Profile 4</a>
<a href='/1_john.smith_1'>Profile 5</a>
```

my user contains `-._ letters and digit` in the user ID
**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$    index.php?view=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*[\.]*[a-z0-9_-]+)/?$    index.php?view=profile [NC,L]
```

the problem is only the second rule is applied 
means whichever link i clicked it goes to `index.php?view=profile`
please tell me the proper way of using this

Comment: Whenever you have trouble with rewriting: USE THE REWRITING LOG! You need the two commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` which mod_rewrite provides. Then the module tells in in all desired details what it is doing internally.

Comment: oh plz tell me how to do it :(

Comment: I did tell you above. Read the excellent manual which comes with the rewriting module. Only if you have questions _after_ that, then ask here :-) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

The first rule will match the second and third link, only these contain only small letters as required by the rule you implemented.

Comment: but the second rule is matching for all links, this is what my problem

Comment: This cannot be explained by the regular expressions you use. So take my advice: use logging. Everything else is digging in the dark...